# ¿Qué apellido aparece en este texto?

Tags: identificación-de-término

Estoy tratando de reconocer en una partida de nacimiento un apellido, estoy entre Gonzalez, Goncalves o Cascales.

¿Me podíais abrir un poco la mente y reconocer el segundo apellido marcado en amarillo?

[image]

[image]

Comment: En vista de cómo es la "G" de "García", y de cómo son las "n" en el resto del documento, yo diría que la palabra marcada no tiene ni "G" ni "n", así que debe de ser "Cascales".

Answer (score 8):

A juzgar por el patrón de escritura del calígrafo puede interpretarse que el apellido en cuestión corresponde al de

> Antonio Riquelme ***Cascales***

Ante mis ojos encuentro dos tipos de caracteres difíciles de reconocer (señalados con "?"). Uno, al inicio (1), y otro, repetido en la posiciones (3) y (8)

> `? a ? c a l e ?`
>
> `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`
>
>
> `C a s c a l e s`

- Para el primero, interpreto que corresponde a una "C" (Ce mayúscula), por ser equivalente al del usado en el apellido "**Cutillas**" (y no una G, al distar mucho de la grafía usada en el apellido "**García**")
- Para el segundo par en duda, entiendo que correspondería una "s" (ese minúscula), al ser la misma letra reconocible para la palabra "**ambos**"

Comment: Me has dejado ANODADATO y PATIDIFUSO ante tu comentarios, MIL gracias¡¡¡